# zref-abspage needs defining a label, but zref-nextpage does not. Why?

Tags: zref

I am looking for a straightforward way to get the absolute page number at the current position. I came across package `zref-abspage` (the programmer's interface) out of the `oberdiek` bundle.

Why do I need to define a label myself in order to get the `abspage` property? Why does the package not do this automatically for me? This is cumbersome, because in order to generate a unique label, I have to define and maintain yet another counter variable.

By contrast, the `zref-nextpage` module does not have this requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{zref-nextpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcount\loopcnt

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\whiledo{\loopcnt<300}{ %about 7 pages of output
  \noindent%
  \zref@labelbyprops{mylabel\the\loopcnt}{abspage}%
  \zref@extract{mylabel\the\loopcnt}{abspage},
  \znextpage\\ % no label required
  \advance\loopcnt by 1
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the package does something is imho a rather senseless question. If you think a feature is missing add an issue to the issue tracker.

Comment: @Ulrike Could be an option, indeed.

Comment: I guess the reason is expandibility. A command for extracting the abs. page number without passing it a label would not be expandible, because it would have to define a unique label internally and write it to `*.aux`. The user command `\znextpage` does exactly this and is therefore, well, not expandible.